# Tables are not generated in abi file

Tags: smart-contract, abi

I have the contract

```
class test : public contract {
public:
    using contract::contract;

    test(account_name self) : contract(self) {}

...

private:
    struct test_rec
    {
        test_hash hash;
        account_name creator;

        uint64_t primary_key() const { return hash; }
        account_name get_creator() const { return creator; }
    };

    typedef eosio::multi_index<N(tests), test_rec > tests;
};
```

So, when I am generating abi file, tables section is empty.

```
...
"tables": [],
...
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you need // @abi table tests i64 above the table

Comment: you should declare @abi table test_rec i64 above your table struct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the below snippet:

```
// @abi table tests i64
struct test_rec
{
    test_hash hash;
    account_name creator;

    uint64_t primary_key() const { return hash; }
    account_name get_creator() const { return creator; }

};

typedef eosio::multi_index<N(tests), test_rec > tests;
```

Comment: may i ask you why we need to add "test i64" after "@abi table" ?  what is the "test i64" for ?

Comment: it's just to force the type of your primary key... in the past sometimes it was getting lost, not sure how the abi generator is now but I always force the primary key type as a safety measurement

Comment: @LeoRibeiro Thanks for your help. But still I cannot understand. Why the examples from eos/contracts doesn't have this semantic? and they are working.

Comment: because maybe the abi generator is fixed. when you have complex types on your primary key field it was returning `i64i64i64` which breaks the abi. now it must be fixed.. you can just not use it and when you get the above problem you can force it as I do

Comment: @LeoRibeiro why you don't use // `abi table test_rec i64`   because table is of struct `test_rec` we typedef your struct later as `tests`.

Comment: This does not work for the latest version as of today

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes with the latest EOSIO versions. First, use the attributes coming from C++ 11, `[[eosio::contract]]`, `[[eosio::action]]` and `[[eosio::table]]`.

```
struct [[eosio::table]] user
{
    uint64_t id;
    string name;
    uint64_t age;
    string address;

    uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
};
```

If the structure is too complex you may need to fix broken parts in the ABI during the generation or manually create the tables in the ABI. Check the link for more information - [Understanding ABI Files](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/the-abi)